# How to load div with jQuery AJAX and setInterval in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am working with jQuery Ajax. I want to load data of my table every 5 seconds. Here's what I tried but it's not working. It doesn't return any error or result.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}

public PartialViewResult _List()
{
  List<Purchase> model = db.Purchases.ToList();
  return PartialView("_List", model);
}
```

```html
<div id="loadList"></div>

@section scripts{
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      setInterval(function () {
        $("#loadList").load("~/Views/Purchases/_List.cshtml");
      }, 3000);
    });
  </script>
}
```

The Partial View which I want to load in `#loadList` `div`.

```
@model IEnumerable<ChocolateFactory.Data.Purchase>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RefNo)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Amount)</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RefNo)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

The partial View is in:

```
~/Views/Purchases/_List.cshtml
```

Comment: You have to pass the url of the controller method that returns the view,  not the `.cshtml` file name in the `.load()` function - e.g. `.load("@Url.Action("_List", YourController");`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I also tried this. but it's not working. The `#loadList` is not loading in Index view.

Comment: `$("#loadList").load("@Url.Action("_List", YourController")` works just fine. What errors are you getting in the browser console? And we do not know what your `_List.cshtml` view is

Comment: I updated question. and it doesn't return any error. Sorry for my English bro.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the tilde character is a Razor construct for the root of the site. It's not recognised outside of that, hence it won't work in your JS code. As you've placed this logic within a view, you can use `@Url.Content()` to parse the URL before outputting it to the JS:

```
setInterval(function () {
  $("#loadList").load("@Url.Content("~/Views/Purchases/_List.cshtml")");
}, 3000);
```

Also note that if your routing is configured properly, then you can use `Url.Action()` which would be more robust, eg `@Url.Action("_List", "ControllerNameHere");`

*However*, it should be noted that making an AJAX request to your server every 3 seconds is not a good idea. It doesn't scale at all, and will cause performance issues. If you need to keep the serve data and client UI in close sync, then a much better idea would be to use Server Sent Events or WebSockets.